# Why Firefox goes zaggy when I have hardware accelaration enabled?

Tags: windows, firefox, hardware-acceleration

I am using Firefox Nightly for now. I have seen same thing if I used Latest Firefox version.
from Firefox 15 if I have enabled the Hardware acceleration in

option > browser > use hardware acceleration.

if I disabled it I can stop seeing the jaggies  but it's can be seen if I enabled it.

Do someone know why this happen.

[image: 1]

I have this problem in Win7 and Win8 both.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What video hardware do you have?

Comment: I have tested same issue in Windows 8 and 7 Both.

Comment: Does it remain with other themes?

Comment: Which graphics card/on-board graphics chipset do you have?

Comment: I have intel G41 Express graphic chipset. @Ernestas Yes, I have this issue with default and other theme as well as this.

Comment: Have you upgraded your video drivers to the latest version?